# Running spring boot application on GCP: nginx reverse proxy : Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 502 (Bad Gateway)

Tags: java, spring-boot, nginx, google-cloud-platform, nginx-reverse-proxy

We are working on spring boot application (backend) and angular6 (frontend)
To deploy our application, we used compute engine of google cloud platform.
We install Java 8, spring boot cli, and postgreSQL, our database.
When we run the application locally to the Virtual machine, everything is ok.
To deploy the application, we follow these steps for configuration: 
[image]

[image]

But at least, we cannot get the application running, 
here the screenshot:
[image]

Your help is more than welcome!